# How to run sikuli scripts on eclipse using jbehave?

Tags: eclipse, bdd, jbehave, sikuli-script

I've just discovered Sikuli and managed to get it running on eclipse. Now I'm trying to figure out if I can use BDD alongside with it, but I can't seem to get them to work together.

I'm using JBehave to run the tests. Here's what I have so far:

**The story file**

```
Scenario:  Opening the orders list
Given i am in the main menu
When i click the orders button
Then the orders list should be opened
```

**The steps file**

```java
package com.test;

import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Then;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.Steps;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

public class AbrirListagemPedidosSteps  extends Steps {
    Screen s;

    public AbrirListagemPedidosSteps() {
        s = new Screen();   
    }


    @Given("i'm in the main menu")
    public void theSystemIsOpened() throws FindFailed {
        s.click("/com/test/images/editSenha.jpg");
        s.type("1");
        s.click("/com/test/images/btnEntrar.jpg");
    }

    @When("i click the orders button")
    public void iClickTheOrdersButton() throws FindFailed {
        s.click("/com/test/images/btnPedido.jpg");
    }

    @Then("the orders list should be opened")
    public void ordersListShouldBeOpened() throws FindFailed {
        s.find("/com/test/images/listagemPedidos");
    }

}
```

**The configuration file**

```java
package com.test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporterBuilder;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InstanceStepsFactory;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Sikulix;

public class AbrirListagemPedidos extends Sikulix {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed {
        AbrirListagemPedidos test = new AbrirListagemPedidos();
        test.configuration();
        test.stepsFactory();
        test.storyPaths();
    }

    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
                .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass()))
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                        new StoryReporterBuilder().withDefaultFormats().withFormats(Format.CONSOLE));
    }

    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new AbrirListagemPedidosSteps());
    }

    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
        return Arrays.asList("/com/test/AbrirListagemPedidos.story");
    }
}
```

As far as I know Sikuli needs a main[] method to execute, so I tried this approach.

I've searched a lot and couldn't find a tutorial or something on how to make this setup works. Running this thows no error, it just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tries I finally did it, but using Cucumber instead of JBehave.

Below is the final code.

**The configuration file - AbrirListagemPedidos.java**

```java
package com.test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "path_to_project_folder\\com\\test", tags = "@ListaPedidosTeste", 
glue = "path_to_project_folder\\com\\test\\stepdefinitions", monochrome = true, dryRun = false)*

public class AbrirListagemPedidos {
}
```

**The feature file - AbrirListagemPedidos.feature**

```
@ListaPedidosTeste
Feature:  Opening the orders list
Scenario: Opening the orders list

Given i am in the main menu
When i click the orders button
Then the orders list should be opened
```

**The steps file - AbrirListagemPedidosSteps.java**

```java
package com.test.stepdefinitions;


import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class AbrirListagemPedidosSteps {
    Screen s;

    public AbrirListagemPedidosSteps() {
        s = new Screen();
    }


    @Given("^i am in the main menu$")
    public void i_am_in_the_main_menu() throws Throwable {
        s.click("/com/test/images/editSenha.jpg");
        s.type("1");
        s.click("/com/test/images/btnEntrar.jpg");
    }

    @When("^i click the orders button$")
    public void i_click_the_orders_button() throws Throwable {
        s.click("/com/test/images/btnPedido.jpg");
    }

    @Then("^the orders list should be opened$")
    public void the_orders_list_should_be_opened() throws Throwable {
        s.find("/com/test/images/listagemPedidos.jpg");
    }

}
```